# Alexa should spell out every character

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I'm creating an Alexa skill. In this skill Alexa should say "U2". But in my case it's neither the band nor "you too".

My skill is in German, so Alexa should say "U" "2" in German as it does for "U3".

When I use:

```
<say-as interpret-as="spell-out">U2</say-as>
```

or:

```
<say-as interpret-as="characters">U2</say-as>
```

the result is "Y O U Leerzeichen T O O" ("Leerzeichen" = Space).

This seems to be a bug. Is there maybe a workaround? Exept of using phonetic pronunciation?

Comment: Do I understand correctly that it's using english pronunciation only when the combination is U2 not for Un, where n is any number except 2 ?

Comment: Yes, that's right. Alexa wants to say "you too". Like CU --> See you.

Comment: Yes but _only_ for "2" , not "1", not "3" ... in those cases it says "U eins" ...?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: What happens if you add a space between U and 2 => `<say-as>U 2</say-as>` ?

Comment: That's "U zwei", thanks. I think this is the workaround I will use for now. As a card it is not so pretty, but better than "you too" ;)

Comment: That's really odd. "U2" must have a hell of a contract with amazon.

Comment: That's what I have thought, too xD